# alternative of left join OR condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, left-join

left join with or condition reduces query performance so what could be alternative of left join or condition

```
select tableb.columnA, tableb.columnB,tablec.id,tabled.id,tablee.id
from tableA tableA
LEFT JOIN tableb tableb ON ((tableb.columnA = tableA.id)
                         OR (tableb.columnB = tableA.id))

LEFT JOIN tablec tablec ON tablec.Id = tableb.columnA 
LEFT JOIN tabled tabled ON tabled.id = tableb.columnB
LEFT JOIN tablee tablee ON tablee.Id= tableb .id
```

Comment: Why involve tablec and tabled, since you don't select any of their columns?

Comment: Are `tableA.id`, `tableb.columnA` and `tableb.columbB` all indexed?  I suspect you may find that they are not and therefore the impact of adding the `OR` condition is much greater than it should be

Comment: @Martin yes all the columns is indexed

Comment: @jarlh i need this table data but i forgot to add in this question

Answer (score 0):

I would start from joining `tableb` again on `columnb` in separate `join`.

On the other joins you can utilize the `ISNULL` function like so `tablec.Id = ISNULL(tableba.columnA, tablebb.columnA)`.

Depends on what you need and your data you can use `UNION`/`UNION ALL` or `COALESCE` to get data from proper instance of `tableb`.

And assure that both columns in `tableb` are coverted by index.

Comment: but i am using tableb  columns to other table for left join after tableb left join